# Fourier series of a polynomial.

Tags: integration, fourier-series, gamma-function

I am looking for the Fourier series of a monomial restricted to the inteval $(0,2\pi)$.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
$$\forall x\in (0, 2\pi), \ f(x)=x^n.$$
By definition, the Fourier coefficients are
$$c_k = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} x^n e^{-ikx} dx,$$
and we know that
$$f(x) =_{\text{a.e.}} \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} c_k e^{ikx}.$$
This can be written in terms of gamma incomplete function, but there might be a closed form for this particular definite integral.

What is the exact value of $c_k$, the Fourier coefficient of the monomial $x^n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the dependence on $n$ explicit, let's write $$c(k,n) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} x^n e^{-ikx}\; dx$$
For $k = 0$, we have
$$ c(0,n) = \frac{(2 \pi)^n}{n+1} $$
For $n=0$ and $k \ne 0$, $c(k,0) = 0$, while by an integration by parts
$$ c(k,n+1) = \frac{(2\pi)^n i}{k} - i (n+1)\frac{c(k,n)}{k}$$
and by induction we can prove (for $k \ne 0$)
$$ c(k,n) = - \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{n!}{(n+1-j)!} \frac{(-i)^j (2\pi)^{n-j}}{k^j} $$

Comment: Do you know any source where such formula is found?

Comment: In the second formula, $c(0,n)$, it must say $c(0,n)=\frac{(2\pi)^{n+1}}{n+1}$ instead.

Comment: @DrPotato No, it must not. Did you forget the $1/(2\pi)$ in front?

Comment: Finding a rational expression for this Fourier series would be useful.

Comment: Is this formula valid for negative powers $k<0$?

Comment: @DrPotato  Yes it is.

Comment: As stated [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linearity-and-conjugation-property-of-continuous-time-fourier-series), for real valued signals in time domain, the conjugate symmetry property of the Fourier series states that
$$c(-k,n)=\overline{c(k,n)}$$
its conjugate. Since in this sum $c(k,n)$ the power of $x$ and $i$ are the same we conclude direct substitution in this formula for $k$ is possible, thus it is valid for negative $k$ as well.